# Javascript getting into infinite loop

Tags: javascript, php, infinite-loop

When i unchecked the input checkboxes the share.php javascript goes into an infinite loop opening new windows.

with all 3 checked no problem occur.

in some point it is going wrong but i cant find where.
Im not sure why it is happening

```
<form action="functions/share.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <p>
        <textarea class="form-control" style="resize: none;height: 90px;padding: 10px;border-radius: 3px;" name="summary" required>Build a fully customizable Personal Website in seconds - for free.</textarea>
    </p>

    <div class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="LinkedIn" value="yes" checked><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="FaceBook" value="yes" checked><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Twitter" value="yes" checked><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
    </div>

    <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="Share" ></p>
</form>
```

**share.php**

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['summary'])){
        $linkedIn = "";
        $faceBook = "";
        $twitter = "";

        if($_POST['LinkedIn'] == "yes"){
            $linkedIn = "http://www.linkedin.com/";
        }

        if($_POST['FaceBook'] == "yes"){
            $faceBook = "http://www.facebook.com/";
        }

        if($_POST['Twitter'] == "yes"){
            $twitter = "http://www.twitter.com/";
        }

    }

?>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="linkedin" style="display: none;">
        <?php 
            echo htmlspecialchars($linkedIn); 
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="facebook" style="display: none;">
        <?php 
            echo htmlspecialchars($faceBook); 
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="twitter" style="display: none;">
        <?php 
            echo htmlspecialchars($twitter); 
        ?>
    </div>
    <script>

         var div = document.getElementById("linkedin");
         var linkedin= div.textContent;
         var div = document.getElementById("facebook");
         var faceBook= div.textContent;
         var div = document.getElementById("twitter");
         var twitter= div.textContent;

         if(linkedin != " "){

            window.open(linkedin);
         };
         if(faceBook != " "){

            window.open(faceBook);
         };
         if(twitter != " "){

            window.open(twitter);
         };

         close();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: give the submit button the name `summary`.Why are you using `htmlspecialchars` in your php code?You can't use your php variables in the JS code. why are you checking if the link equals " " and not ""?

Comment: there is no php code in the js code. summary is being sent as post no need to add into the button. htmlspecialchars because i need to keep it as html code not filtered text. the " " instead of "" was just a try.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger?

Comment: @Mawg there is no debugger for PHP.

Comment: If you don't know what you are talking about, then please don't post. I have debugged PHP using NetBeans, CodeLobster and PHPstorm. Yes, you can debug PHP and I would recommend you to look into it. It will make you a far more productive developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing,You must change the checking sentence from

`if($_POST['LinkedIn'] == "yes")`

to
 `if(isset($_POST['LinkedIn']))`

Second thing,you must remove the close sentence in your JS code `close();`

when you make those two changes, the checked links will open. If there were a box that is not checked then a window will open with link `http://localhost/functions/share.php`. to solve this problem declare the links inside the 'JS' code.

Your final code:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['summary'])){
        $linkedIn = "";
        $faceBook = "";
        $twitter = "";

        if(isset($_POST['LinkedIn']))
            $linkedIn = htmlspecialchars("http://www.linkedin.com/");
        else
            $linkedIn = "";

        if(isset($_POST['FaceBook']))
            $faceBook = htmlspecialchars("http://www.facebook.com/");
        else
            $faceBook = "";

        if(isset($_POST['Twitter']))
            $twitter = htmlspecialchars("http://www.twitter.com/");
        else
            $twitter = "";

    }

?>
<html>
<body>
    <script>

         var linkedin= "<?php echo $linkedIn; ?>";
         var faceBook= "<?php echo $faceBook; ?>";
         var twitter= "<?php echo $twitter; ?>";

         if(linkedin != "")
            window.open(linkedin);
         if(faceBook != "")
            window.open(faceBook);
         if(twitter != "")
            window.open(twitter);
         //close();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: may i know why to remove the close() at the end?  without it the receiving page share.php will not close. i will test your answer and will accept if works.